# asp.net mvc get current logged in user id

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get the UserID of a User object in ASP.Net MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924692/how-do-you-get-the-userid-of-a-user-object-in-asp-net-mvc)

Greetings, 
I have created a custom membership provider to make it possible to authenticate users on my application. How can i retrieve current user id in controller? I need this to get some data from database for this user like this:

```
PersistanceManger.RepositoryUser.GetInformation(userROWGUID);
```

Comment: How are user authenticated in the application? Does it use Windows, Forms, or some sort of custom authentication scheme?

Comment: I use Forms for authentication

Answer (score 3):

Do you particularly need the Id of the user or the userName ?, it seems you are looking for the Guid of the present user, for this I think the retrieval of this Id depends on your implementation. If you want to retrieve information based of userName, then you can do the following:

`HttpContext.Current.User` gives you the User object, you can get the other information from it, for your case, you need to use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`

Comment: Question is asking for how to find Guid?