# get current logged in userID in aspnet mvc membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am trying to show a list of users of my application "school", when admin logs in then he can view all the users in list but when school principals logins, he should get only users of his school, So i thought to get the current loggedIn userId first and then by that userId i'll get schoolId since userId is foreign key in school table...once i'll get the schoolId i can show the members of that school.

But my problem is how to get the UserID of currently loggedIn. I'm using MVC 1.0 Asp.Net -- "Membership"

if my logic above is wrong then please tell me the alternate good idea, so that principal can see only his users list..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Simple Solution**
With the scenario you describe you would only be able to do this by retrieving the User information with the data stored in the HttpContext.Current.Identity. For example, if the HttpContext.Current.Identity.Name is the Username, then you would use that value to retrieve the User data for the principal that should include the UserId you can use to locate the appropriate school.

**Alternate Solution**
You might consider storing the SchoolId in the user's profile so that it is more easily accessible.

Comment: ok, thx i'm so novice, but now i have 1 more doubt, how can i retrieve the user data using "HttpContext.Current.Identity.Name". if i would have used my own membership controller then i would have queried but i'm using aspnet membership, so how to do that ?

Answer (score 21):

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924692/how-do-you-get-the-userid-of-a-user-object-in-asp-net-mvc) and answer by J. Pablo Fernández you can get the user id of the current user with the following code:

```
//It will only be a Guid if you are using SQL Server as the DB as oppose to MySQL
Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```

Here is the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getuser.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way that I've tried

You have to include `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

Then use it like this

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString();
```